# geoLocation or geoNear using let variables for coordinates and radius

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm running an aggregate on my 'Users' collection to assign a list of cities that are within some radius of the users coordinates.

It seems that theres no way to assign let variables to the `maxDistance` field as this can only accept raw numbers.

Is there another way I can do the same kind of calculation not using `$geoNear`, or `$geoWithin` as both of these have the same limitations.

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'cities'
  let: {
    userCoordinates: '$coordinates',
    userSearchRadius: '$searchRadius'
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $geoNear: {
        near: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: '$$userCoordinates'
        },
        distanceField: 'distance',
        maxDistance: '$$userSearchRadius', // Issue here
        spherical: true,
      }
    }
  ],
  as: 'nearbyCities'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to your issue would be adding a `$match` stage after the `$geoNear` stage on the calculated `distance` field.

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "cities",
      let: {
        "userCoordinate": "$coordinate",
        "userSearchRadius": "$searchRadius"
      },
      as: "nearByCities",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: "$$userCoordinate",
            spherical: true,
            distanceField: "distance"
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                "$distance",
                "$$userSearchRadius"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$nearByCities",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J45rjbtem_c)